# Port forwarding not working in android emulator

Tags: java, android, port, emulation, forwarding

I am trying to send data to server using socket programming. The server is in android and the client is in my host machine. The program works fine and the app runs perfectly. But when I try to forward the port from host machine to emulator, it says

> KO: bad redirection format, try (tcp|udp):hostport:guestport

The command I used is

> redir add tcp:4000:3000

What am I missing here?

Comment: `The server is in android`. In the emulator you mean?

Comment: `the client is in my host machine`. What do you mean by that? On which machine is the emulator running?

Comment: Ya.. I meant the emulator @greenapps

Comment: I'm running the client in my windows and the server is in emulator

Comment: And where is the emulator running? I asked that before.

Comment: I don't get you. The emulator is running in the same machine as the client. Is that what you ask?

Comment: That i wanted to know yes. Why did you not tell us right away?

Comment: Which ip does the client use to reach the server in the emulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution by myself. To be specific, I'll explain the scenario once again. I have a server socket running in android emulator, and a client in my host machine. BTW, both client and emulator runs on the same machine. I used 'localhost' to reach the server(running in emulator). And to forward the port, I used

> adb forward tcp:hostport tcp:guestport

According to my example, the command will be

> adb forward tcp:4000 tcp:3000

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that what you have experienced is a pure typing error.

While typing commands in the Android Emulator Console, it is important to avoid typos, as the backspace does not clear the character as you would expect.

So even if the syntax of your command was correct, you must have made typing errors which you tried to clear with a backspace.